# Merge List of columns and List of Data into List C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I am facing some problem to merge two lists into a single list by using **`LINQ`** and **`C#`**.
My scenario is that in `List one` I got the number of `columns` and in `second list` I am getting `data` correspondent column list.
The similarity between the two lists is their `indexes`.

Currently, I am using List of the dictionary to do this job but I need data as a `model list`.

[image: ROW Data]

[image: Column Data]

**Here is my code**

```
/* Loop over the result set and create a dictionary with column name for key and data for value */
List<Dictionary<String, String>> scanLists = new List<Dictionary<String, String>>();

if (resResp.ResultSet.Rows.Count > 1)
{
    /*First cloumn always contains column names so we have to remove those*/
    //resResp.ResultSet.Rows.Remove(resResp.ResultSet.Rows[0]);
    foreach (Row row in resResp.ResultSet.Rows)
    {
        Dictionary<String, String> scanData = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        for (var i = 0; i < resResp.ResultSet.ResultSetMetadata.ColumnInfo.Count; i++)
        {
            scanData.Add(resResp.ResultSet.ResultSetMetadata.ColumnInfo[i].Name, row.Data[i].VarCharValue);
        }
        scanLists.Add(scanData);
    }
}
```

But I want result in in

```
List<ScanData> scanList = new  List<ScanData>();
```

Thank you ALL

Comment: Do you need the keys stored in the scanData?  I assume they'd be retrievable from the scanData values, no?

Comment: @Immersive I need key as column name like property of class.

Comment: As far as I can tell, all your code is doing is recreating the rows/columns table in memory ("rows of column data").  Why?  Conversion to an object/class will simplify many things about this problem in both how you think and how you code.  What is your end-goal?

Comment: @Immersive Actually I am getting this data from a third-party tool (aws Athena) so need to perform some manipulation like (Searching , Sorting etc...) into it because it is very tough to manipulate data into Dictionary that's why I need to convert this dictionary into a model list.

Answer (score 1):

Try a homegrown Object-Relational Mapping:

```
var scanObjects = new List<MyCustomObject>();

foreach (Row row in resResp.ResultSet.Rows)
{
    var myObject = new MyCustomObject();
    //Dictionary<String, String> scanData = new Dictionary<String, String>();
    for (var i = 0; i < resResp.ResultSet.ResultSetMetadata.ColumnInfo.Count; i++)
    {
        //scanData.Add(resResp.ResultSet.ResultSetMetadata.ColumnInfo[i].Name, row.Data[i].VarCharValue);

        switch( resResp.ResultSet.ResultSetMetadata.ColumnInfo[i].Name )
        {
            case "ExampleId":
                myObject.ExampleId = row.Data[i].VarCharValue;
                break;
            case "ExampleValue":
                myObject.ExampleValue = row.Data[i].VarCharValue;
                break;
            default:
                // Unrecognised/unused column
                break;
        }
    }
    //scanLists.Add(scanData);
    scanObjects.Add(myObject);
}
```

Comment: I accept this answer but column can be dynamic is there any generic solution of this  problem.